# django rest framework - how to add a static field value for a serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to add a static field to my serializer. It should always return the same value, regardless of the passed object. Currently I implemented it like so:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_type(obj):
        return 'question'

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('type',)
```

But is there a simpler way to do it, without the `SerializerMethodField`?

Comment: I think this is the correct way to do it. I don't know any better way.

Answer (score 28):

using a ReadOnlyField worked for me:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(default='question')

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('type',)
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#readonlyfield

Comment: Note that if your model has a member with the same name (e.g. `'type'`), `ReadOnlyField` will use that instead.

Answer (score 7):

The only alternative would be to override `to_representation` and add the value there:

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
    data = super().to_representation(obj)
    data['type'] = 'question'
    return data
```

Not a much better option though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `serializers.HiddenField`

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.HiddenField(default='question')

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('type',)
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield

Comment: this does not seem to appear when serialized out

Comment: `HiddenField` never ends up being serialized, it's only available "internally".

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about adding a line to your model, it would be easier to add static field to your model.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    type = 'question'

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('type',)
```